# Como imprimir pares e suas posições em VisuAlg

Tags: visualg

Olá!

Tenho o seguinte exercício: "Peça ao utilizador 10 números inteiros. Saiba quais são os pares e quais as suas posições no vetor."

Devo usar VisuAlg e vetores.

Tenho:

```
Algoritmo "10 números pares e as suas posições"

Var
   valor: vetor[1..10] de inteiro
   contador, contPar, par: inteiro


Inicio

      contador <- 1
      contPar <- 0

      enquanto contador <= 5 faca
               Escreva("Indique o número: ")
               leia(valor[contador])
               se valor[contador] % 2 = 0 entao
                  par <- valor[contador]
                  contPar <- contPar + 1

               fimse

               contador <- contador + 1          
     fimenquanto
     
escreval("O número ",par," é par e está na ",contPar,"ª posição.")
Fimalgoritmo
```

O algoritmo imprime:

```
Indique o número: 6
Indique o número: 2
Indique o número: 5
Indique o número: 3
Indique o número: 1
O número  2 é par e está na  2ª posição.
```

Reconhece o par, mas apenas 1 deles. O que posso fazer?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que no final do seu código, vc apenas colocou pra imprimir uma linha

```
escreval("O número ",par," é par e está na ",contPar,"ª posição.")
```

Nesse caso, sugiro que vc faça duas edições no código, crie dois vetores: um para armazenar os números pares e um vetor para armazenar as posições, então no loop final vc só precisa percorrer os dois vetores e terá todos os números pares e suas respectivas posições.

Comment: Olá, Roland. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Tentei assim: https://prnt.sc/10eeoff
E deu isto: https://prnt.sc/10eeovl

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar resumir:

- preencher o vetor;
- para cada posição do vetor. Se o número for par. Exibe o número a sua posição.

Sobre:

> Reconhece o par, mas apenas 1 deles. O que posso fazer? Obrigado

É que você esta tentando "salvar" os resultados... mas precisaria assimilar que uma variável só armazena um valor, ou seja: a cada novo par, você está atualizando a mesma variável, logo, ela só vai ficar com o último valor atribuído. Um outro ponto é que a posição que se procura é a posição no vetor, mas você meio que está tentado contar a quantidade de pares... são coisas distintas.

A posição do número estaria na variável `contador` mesmo. Exemplos:

#### Varrendo o próprio vetor

```
algoritmo "10 números pares e as suas posições"
var
   numeros: vetor[1..10] de inteiro
   contador, contPar, par: inteiro
inicio
   contador <- 0
   contPar <- 0

   escreval("Informe 10 números inteiros")

   ALEATORIO 1, 100
   para contador de 1 ate 10 faca
      escreva (contador:2, "º número: ")
      leia(numeros[contador])
   fimPara
   ALEATORIO OFF

   escreval()
   escreval("Relação de números pares")
   escreval()
   escreval("Numero  -  Posição")
   escreval("------------------")
   para contador de 1 ate 10 faca
      se numeros[contador] % 2 = 0 entao
         escreval(numeros[contador]:4, contador:11)
      fimSe
   fimPara
fimAlgoritmo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Armazenando os dados em outros vetores

```
algoritmo "10 números pares e as suas posições"
var
   numeros: vetor[1..10] de inteiro
   pares, posicoes: vetor[1..10] de inteiro
   contPares, i: inteiro
   contador, contPar, par: inteiro
inicio
   contador <- 0
   contPar <- 0

   escreval("Informe 10 números inteiros")

   ALEATORIO 1, 100
   para contador de 1 ate 10 faca
      escreva (contador:2, "º número: ")
      leia(numeros[contador])
   fimPara
   ALEATORIO OFF

   escreval()
   escreval("Relação de números pares")
   escreval()
   escreval("Numero  -  Posição")
   escreval("------------------")

   contPares <- 0
   para contador de 1 ate 10 faca
      se numeros[contador] % 2 = 0 entao //se for par
         contPares <- contPares + 1 //atualiza o contador de pares
         pares[contPares] <- numeros[contador] //armazena o par
         posicoes[contPares] <- contador //armazena a posição desse par
      fimSe
   fimPara

   para i de 1 ate contPares faca
      escreval(pares[i]:4, posicoes[i]:11)
   fimPara
fimAlgoritmo
```

Obs.: o resultado é exatamente igual ao anterior, por isso não vou postar outra imagem.

Comment: Uma outra forma interessante seria utilizando um registro combinando com um vetor, desta forma, seria possível "agrupar" a informação do valor do número par com a sua respectiva posição no vetor inicial.